# Windows Phone 8.1 Xmal With Azure Mobile Service Deployment Error: [MissingManifestResource_NoPRIresources]

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, azure-mobile-services, appx, appxmanifest

I am using Azure Mobile Service Offline with Windows Phone 8.1 (XAML).

When I am using app with debug mode it is working fine.

But, If i create package with Release mode. It Throw an error.

and that is [MissingManifestResource_NoPRIresources]

[image]
Currently I am using Following references in my Project

```
<ItemGroup>
<Reference Include="GalaSoft.MvvmLight">
  <HintPath>..\packages\MvvmLightLibs.5.0.2.0\lib\wpa81\GalaSoft.MvvmLight.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras">
  <HintPath>..\packages\MvvmLightLibs.5.0.2.0\lib\wpa81\GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Platform">
  <HintPath>..\packages\MvvmLightLibs.5.0.2.0\lib\wpa81\GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Platform.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation">
  <HintPath>..\packages\CommonServiceLocator.1.3\lib\portable-net4+sl5+netcore45+wpa81+wp8\Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile">
  <HintPath>..\packages\WindowsAzure.MobileServices.1.3.0\lib\wpa81\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Ext">
  <HintPath>..\packages\WindowsAzure.MobileServices.1.3.0\lib\wpa81\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Ext.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.SQLiteStore">
  <HintPath>..\packages\WindowsAzure.MobileServices.SQLiteStore.1.0.0\lib\portable-win+net45+wp8+wpa81+monotouch+monoandroid\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.SQLiteStore.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.6.0.4\lib\portable-net45+wp80+win8+wpa81\Newtonsoft.Json.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="SQLitePCL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\SQLitePCL.3.8.5.1\lib\wpa81\SQLitePCL.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System.Net.Http.Extensions">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Http.2.2.28\lib\wpa81\System.Net.Http.Extensions.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System.Net.Http.Primitives">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Http.2.2.28\lib\wpa81\System.Net.Http.Primitives.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="WinRTXamlToolkit">
  <HintPath>..\packages\WinRTXamlToolkit.WindowsPhone.1.7.9.0\lib\wpa\WinRTXamlToolkit.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Comment: Also Using SQLite for Windows Phone 8.1                            <SDKReference Include="SQLite.WP81, Version=3.8.7.4">
      <Name>SQLite for Windows Phone 8.1</Name>
    </SDKReference>

Comment: We've responded on the GitHub issue (https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-services/issues/616)--there's a bug in the .NET framework that is failing to load the resource string. You're probably going through a different code path in the published app and that is triggering the bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It got resolved when we update to
Azure Mobile Services Managed SDK: Version 1.3.2

Thanks  [lindydonna](https://stackoverflow.com/users/291485/lindydonna)